# ftp.cwd() I dont understand the error

Tags: python, ftp

When i run this code:

```
for i in range(len(ftp_folders)): #ftp_folders[] list

    ftp.cwd(ftp_folders[i]) #first interaction __> ftp.folders[Templates]
    print(ftp.pwd()) #entering int the folder 
    print('entering in : ',ftp_folders[i]) # 1. Templates

    ftp.cwd(ftp_folders[i]) #ERROR WHY??
    ftp.retrlines('LIST')
```

for loop crashes in the first interaction.
I can enter in the first folder of ftp_folders[i] (Templates) but when run the ftp.cwd(), it crashes

error:

```
/home/pi/Templates
```

entering in :  Templates

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\peces\Documents\python\exercises\ftp\ping.pyw", line 47, in <module> ftp.cwd(ftp_folders[i])
File "C:\Users\peces\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\ftplib.py", line 629, in cwd
    return self.voidcmd(cmd)
File "C:\Users\peces\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\ftplib.py", line 276, in voidcmd
    return self.voidresp()
  File "C:\Users\peces\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\ftplib.py", line 249, in voidresp
    resp = self.getresp()
  File "C:\Users\peces\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\ftplib.py", line 244, in getresp
    raise error_perm(resp)
ftplib.error_perm: 550 Templates: No such file or directory
```

No such file or directory?. I cant explain. sure the problem is other..
ftp.cwd(ftp_folders[i]) run as error.. And either know why.

some help?

Comment: Templates exists, in fact the script enter into the folder: /home/pi/Templates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently do the following:

- change the remote directory to `Templates`.

  - since it is a *relative path*, this changes your directory relative to the directory you were in at login.
- print your working directory;
- you now attempt to `cwd Templates` **again**

  - this is a *relative path*, you are attempting to change to the `Templates` subdirectory of the `Templates` directory you are already in.

Note that the format of a path to `CWD` is implementation dependent, but commonly they support:

- paths beginning with `/` indicate an absolute path; while
- paths **not** beginning with `/` indicate a path relative to the current `PWD`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, you are right I try to reenter in the same folder. But when I copied the code I forgot to write comments to the second:  #ftp.cwd(ftp_folders[i]). sorry Commenting this line, I fget the same error.

Answer (score 0):

ok i get it.

at the end of the iteration I had had to write: ftp.cwd('../') in order to  come back in the directory. Writting that i can to come back in the directory and list each folder of the "base" folder: /home/pi.

As a result, plus adding more code it saids:

```
for i in range(len(ftp_folders)):
    print('print before change directory')
    print(ftp.cwd(ftp.pwd()+'/'+ftp_folders[i]))
    print(ftp.pwd())
    print('entering in : ',ftp_folders[i])
    #ftp.cwd('Templates')
    #ftp.cwd(ftp_folders[i])
    ftp.retrlines('LIST')
    ftp.cwd('../')
```

Now it runs.!
thanks a lot @donkopotamus

Comment: If the answer was correct, mark it as such, don't post an answer saying the answer was correct :-)

Comment: thanks again, I marked the answer as correct. ok. no more post answering one of the answer was correct. thanks